# Textarea not respecting line breaks

Tags: wordpress, textarea, bbpress

I'm having a problem with a textarea.

I'm using BBPress of Wordpress. When I public a post, it looks like this on the DB:

```
text text text
text text 
 
[center]text text text[/center]

text text text
```

But When I try to edit this post on the textarea it looks like this:

```
text text text
text text
[center]text text text[/center]
text text text
```

If I save the post it will lose the <br> and the <p></p>
The output changes from:

```
<p>text text <br> text text</p><p></p><p>text text text</p>
```

To:

```
<p>text text text text</p><p>text text text</p>
```

So.. What I need is to retrieve the data of the DB and put it into the textarea without losing those line breaks?

It was working fine but I don't know what happened. :|

If someone could give me a clue I would be grateful : )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was the function that minify the HTML.

That was making my textarea lose the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
text text text
text text 
text text text
text text text
```

Using textarea if you break words. You can try function nl2br() in php

Comment: Thanks, but nl2br do this on my textarea: text text text<br>text text text<br>. I don't want to show tbe html  I want to retrieve it like how it is on my DB. I already tried different things but no one works.